# Exporting data from Lotus Domino

Tags: lotus-notes, ibm-domino

I am looking to see if there is a way to export a user list from Domino with the Alias's listed. Anything I have seen online is to open the address book on a notes client, and build the view, but I cannot find anything pertaining to the alias. If anyone know a way, that would be great.

Comment: Do the users/aliases exist in AD?

Comment: @BartDeVos Users yes aliases no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an agent in your local address book with target "None". Set it to run LotusScript and use this code:

```
Dim ui As New NotesUIWorkspace, ns As New NotesSession, db As NotesDatabase, view As NotesView, doc As NotesDocument, nab As Variant, fname As Variant, fnum As Integer
nab=ui.Prompt(13, "", "")
If Not Isempty(nab) Then
    fname=ui.SaveFileDialog(False)
    If Not Isempty(fname) Then
        fnum=Freefile
        Open fname(0) For Output As #fnum
        Set db=ns.GetDatabase(nab(0), nab(1))
        Set view=db.GetView("($People)")
        Set doc=view.GetFirstDocument
        Do
            Print #fnum, Join(doc.Fullname, Chr$(9))
            Set doc=view.GetNextDocument(doc)
        Loop Until doc Is Nothing
        Close #fnum
    End If
End If
```

Run the agent. Select the address book you want to export users from, then enter a filename for your export file. It will create a user list with aliases tab-separated on each line.